# Visual Studio for Web 2012 - Cant create table in SQL database

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

In Visual Studio For Web, I created a new SQL Database. When in the database explorer in the past i have been able to right click "Tables" and select "Create new table". I am no longer able to do that with the current setup. See below:

- Visual Studio For Web 2012
- SQL Server 2012

However, If I install SQL Server 2008r2 instead of SQL Server 2012 the functionality returns within Visual Studio for Web 2012.

Any idea why it will not work as intended using SQL 2012?

[image: See picture below:]

Comment: How do you know you are no longer able to do that? (In other words, is there an error message or what?)

Comment: Catfood, see the picture I added.

Comment: The "add new table" and "new query" options do not show at all, just "refresh" and "properties".

Comment: Anyone? No one else has seen this issue? Am I the only developer using the internal database management tools?

Comment: Little more clarification please. Are you saying you are installing the *client* pack for SQL Server 2008r2? Or that you're connecting to a 2008r2 server? Also, are you able to create tables with SQL Server 2012 from the SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Running SQL Server 2008r2 SP 1 express and it works. My issue is with SQL Server 2012 Express. I have been developing for years and have never seen this issue. I can create a database and subsequent tables successfully under SSMS. I also changed the default localdb\11.0 instance name in Visual Studio to match the instance name of my SQL Server. "SQLExpress" I have attempted this install on multiple workstations ranging from Windows XP to Windows 8, same problem each time. Works great with 2008r2 and fails with 2012 with the issue portrayed in the picture provided.

Comment: Okay, so what user are you logging in as from Visual Studio? I wonder if this is just a rights issue.

Comment: Perhaps I am being unclear, my apologies. Scenario: Say I open a vm of windows 7, install VS for Web 2012 and SQL 2008r2, and set the VS instance to match the SQL server. I then open VS new project, add an SQL database, go to database explorer and right click on "tables", i get the option to create new tables. Now, if i wipe that vm and create a new exactly the same, but this time install SQL 2012 and attempt the same scenario i get no option to create a table. Was that a bit more clear?

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server 2012, you also need to install the SQL Server Data Tools update:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the database file in the database connection. Click mouse right button on the xxx.mdf and select the [delete] to delete the original database connection.
2. Then rebuilt sql server contenction. Click mouse right button on the Database Conection.
3. Build a new connection for your database